# Is it possible use the Calendar Api to send sms messages to the other person when adding a meeting?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is it possible use the Calendar Api to send sms messages to the other person when adding a meeting?

My Client's client want to send SMS messages via Bambika as a meeting reminder. Is it possible? I have been Googling but not found anything that helps. The Calendar API doesn't have a field for Telephone numbers. Any pointers please? Thanks